# Replace object in array with data from another array's object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Assuming we have 2 arrays:

array1 has 1 event:

```
var array1 = [
      {
      start: '2018-04-24T10:00:00',
      end: '2018-04-24T11:00:00',
      title: 'Been to Break'
    }
  ];
```

array2 has 3 events:

```
  var array2 = [
      {
        start: '2018-04-24T08:00:00',
        end: '2018-04-24T10:00:00',
        title: 'Lunch'
      },
      {
        start: '2018-04-24T10:00:00',
        end: '2018-04-24T11:00:00',
        title: 'Break'
      },
      {
        start: '2018-04-24T13:00:00',
        end: '2018-04-24T14:00:00',
        title: 'Meeting'
      }
    ];
```

Desired results should be a new array: array3

```
var array3 = [
  { //event 1
    start: '2018-04-24T08:00:00',
    end: '2018-04-24T10:00:00',
    title: 'Lunch'
  },
  { //event 2
    start: '2018-04-24T10:00:00',
    end: '2018-04-24T11:00:00',
    title: 'Been to Break'
  },
  { //event 3
    start: '2018-04-24T13:00:00',
    end: '2018-04-24T14:00:00',
    title: 'Meeting'
  }
];
```

You can see from the desired results in array3 that the event 2 in array2 was replaced with the event 1 in array1 since the start and end values are a match.

Can this be done in JavaScript? and what about performance if we have let's say 1000 events to loop through

Thanks

Comment: Is the array sorted by date? Will this search need to be done frequently?

Comment: @CrazyTrain in this example yes, but I have a case where it is not

Comment: If it was sorted and you kept it sorted, you could perform a binary search for much greater performance than a linear search. If this operation will happen somewhat frequently, it may be worth maintaining a sorted ordering, if possible.

Comment: @CrazyTrain just realised the events are pulled from db then they can be sorted prior to assigning them to the array. Is there a workaround to get array3 as per the example. cheers

Comment: Where did `'Breaky'` come from?

Comment: @Paulpro It should be 'Meeting'. My bad, sorry. I've updated the question. Ta

Comment: Yep, just research how do a binary search, and use that so that you're not having to visit *potentially* every object in the array. If you're also manually inserting new objects, use the same search technique to locate the spot to inject the new object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplistic approach would be to loop over the update array (array1) to find a match in array2 and replace it if found.

```js
var array1 = [{
  start: '2018-04-24T10:00:00',
  end: '2018-04-24T11:00:00',
  title: 'Been to Break'
}];

var array2 = [{
    start: '2018-04-24T08:00:00',
    end: '2018-04-24T10:00:00',
    title: 'Lunch'
  },
  {
    start: '2018-04-24T10:00:00',
    end: '2018-04-24T11:00:00',
    title: 'Break'
  },
  {
    start: '2018-04-24T13:00:00',
    end: '2018-04-24T14:00:00',
    title: 'Meeting'
  }
];

array1.forEach((evUpdate) => {
  const matchIndex = array2.findIndex((ev) => ev.start === evUpdate.start && ev.end === evUpdate.end);

  if (matchIndex > -1) {
    array2.splice(matchIndex, 1, evUpdate);
  }
});

console.log(array2);
```

As per performance, there are a lot of other factors that are unknown. For instance, if this is a runtime operation that happens often but the underlying data is fairly static then why not create and store a resultant in a data store?